# Is there a function that is to near() what %in% is to ==?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame or tibble with a numeric column `x`:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- tibble(x = c(0.123456, 0.5678910, 1.234567, 5.67891011, 12.345678),
               y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

In order to filter on rows where `x` is close (with a given tolerance, e.g. `1e-4`) to a set of values, e.g. `c(0.5679, 5.6789)`. I would use something like this:

```
data %>% filter(near(x, 0.5679, 1e-4) | near(x, 5.6789, 1e-4))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 0.568     2
#> 2 5.68      4
```

This gets verbose if I instead of `c(0.5679, 5.6789)` I have a vector of 100 elements... So, is there a function enabling to write something along the lines of:

```
data %>% filter(near_any(x, c(0.5679, 5.6789), tol = 1e-4))
```

In other words, is there a function that is to `near()` what `%in%` is to `==`?

(I can write such a `near_any()` function, but before I want to check if one doesn't already exist)

Created on 2018-07-10 by the reprex package (v0.2.0).

Comment: You’ll almost certainly have to write it yourself. That said, it’s a simple `near_any = function (x, y) any(near(x, y, 1e-4))`. I’d be tempted to forego the function entirely in this case.

Comment: That's not what I want (my result is a vector with the same size as `x`), so rather something along the lines of : `function(x, values, tol) { for (val in values) { result <- result | near(x, val, tol) } return(result) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dplyr` it doesn't exist, in base R most probably not. If you're asking about other packages it's out of SO's scope.

But you can do it this way :

```
data %>%
  filter(Reduce(`|`,lapply(c(0.5679, 5.6789), near, x= x, tol = 1e-4)))

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#          x     y
#      <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 0.567891     2
# 2 5.678910     4
```

Or in tidyverse language using also `purrr` package:

```
data %>%
  filter(reduce(map(c(0.5679, 5.6789), near, x= x, tol = 1e-4),`|`))
```

Comment: Your answer is reimplementing the base R function `any` (just vectorised), and you don’t need to `lapply` over the `y` values but over the `x` values (which is virtually certainly more efficient for large tables).

Comment: not totally true, all my OR operations are vectorized, yours are not, we're just vectorizing at different places. Your might be more efficient, or more efficient in some case though, we'd have to test it.

Comment: My point is that C-level vectorisation is *orders of magnitude* more efficient than R-level vectorisation (i.e. `lapply` or `map`). So taking advantage of the vectorised operations inside `near` should be done for the longer vector.

Comment: I understand you, but in my example I'm looping 2 times on 2 objects (4 iterations), the rest is vectorized, you're looping with `map_lgl` on every element of the x column

Comment: Thanks @Moody_Mudskipper, that's exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: small correction, I have `2*(2-1)` so `2` iterations, not `4`, as `Reduce` applies its function `n-1` times :).

Answer (score 2):

`near(x, y)` is already vectorised, So wrapping it in [`any`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/any.html) yields a single value.

To use it in your case, you then just need to `map` over the `x` values:

```
data %>% filter(map_lgl(x, ~ any(near(.x, c(0.5679, 5.6789), tol = 1e-4))))
```

Comment: This doesn't return the expected output

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I'd rather map / loop over `y`, so I'll go with Moody_Mudskipper's answer. Still upvoted your answer as well as it can be useful for ppl wanting to map over `x` instead.

Comment: @byouness Yes, that’s good reasoning, as I myself explained in my (misplaced) comment on Moody’s answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map_df(c(0.5679,5.6789), function(i) data %>% 
          filter(near(x, i, 1e-4)))


      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1 0.568    2.
2 5.68     4.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use data.tables (very fast) foverlaps()

```
library(data.table)
#create the data.table
data <- data.table( x = c(0.123456, 0.5678910, 1.234567, 5.67891011, 12.345678),
                    y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
#add a min-max column to join  on. they are both eequal to the value of x
data[, c("min", "max") := list(x, x)]

#set the precision
precision <- 1e-4

#create a data.table with filter values and theur range (+/- precision)
filter_values <- setDT(data.table( x = c(0.5679, 5.6789)))
filter_values[, c("min", "max") := list(x - precision, x + precision)]
#set key for join
setkey(filter_values, min, max)

#perform an overlap-join, keep only columns x and y, where a match with a filter_value is found
foverlaps(data,filter_values)[!is.na(x),c("x","y")]

#         x y
# 1: 0.5679 2
# 2: 5.6789 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think another way is to use the round function:

```
data %>% filter(round(x,2) %in% 0.33)
```

**Explanation:**

x was 0.3333333333333 thus making it rounded up to 2 decimal points would make it 0.33.